# Does anyone have experience in using AWS Amplify for hosting?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, hosting, aws-amplify

I've just finished creating my very first web app, and now I'd like to host it using AWS Amplify. It's a very basic web app, utilising only Node.js, Express, MongoDB and Mustache. I realise Amplify might seem overqualified for hosting such a simple web app, but it's necessary now (hard to explain, it just is).

I followed the steps on the AWS Amplify console in order to provision, build and deploy my app, and it all completed successfully, but when I go to the link that Amplify provides (where I expected to see and interact with my app) I get a 404 error.

I was just wondering if anyone could talk me through the bare necessities needed to visit the link and use my app as I intended? I feel I might have gone wrong somewhere with how my code is built or something.